# Hard Drive Not Being Detected

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an external HDD that used to work just fine.  When I took it to another house, and plugged it in, it tried to install drivers, and seemed to work fine, but then the hard drive was appearing in my computer with a letter, but you couldn't open it, and it didn't show size or anything. NOW it's even worse, it's not even showing up in my computer. It just makes the connected USB ding when I plug it in, but there's nothing in my computer. What could I do to try and fix it? I've gone in to drive management, but it doesn't show up in there at all... ideas?

Update:
I ran a live Ubuntu disc.
It seems to be fine when I run disc utility.
I did a benchmark test and it was okay. No warnings of impending failure.
There's a 696mb "file" called filesystem.squashfs. When i try to check / repair it, I get the error "the device is busy" "Device is mounted and no online capability in fsck tool or file system" If I format the file system, since it's not part of the other partition, will I lose data?
I've tried 'sudo lilo -M /dev/sdb mbr'
Not sure how to recover the drive in its state.

Comment: Sounds like the drive has failed I hope you have backups

Comment: This is a backup drive. But it's very odd. It sounds like it's running fine. Is there any tools I can use to check its health?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you can mount the drive and check the contents on the Ubuntu LiveCD ?

Comment: See my update in the main post. It actually worked in Ubuntu, although I still couldn't see the data

Comment: Why are you trying to install LILO onto the drive ? what's the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` ?

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to GUID setup instead of MBR. When I changed it to MBR, it worked again. STRANGE!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the livedisk was reporting itself, not your external HDD

Answer (score 1):

I changed the boot from GUID to MBR and it worked again. I'm not exactly sure how it ended up this way, but that was the fix.